# discord.js react to message by id on ready

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have looked throughout other stack questions, and none of their answers worked for me, so far I have the code

```
client.channels.fetch(`1025902604728934442`)
    .then(channel => {
        channel.messages.fetch(1027438839435907142).react("");
    })
```

it does not work by the way.

I get the following error code:

```
(node:2760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: channel.messages.fetch(...).react is not a function
    at /index.js:76:53
(node:2760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2760) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Are you sure that the channel id exists?

Comment: Can you also add the `eventListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just how you call `.then()` on `channels.fetch()` you have to do so with `messages.fetch()`

```js
client.channels.fetch(`1025902604728934442`)
    .then(channel => {
        channel.messages.fetch("1027438839435907142")
        .then(msg => {
            msg.react("");
        });
    })
```

What you're doing is *resolving a promise* and the code throws an error because you don't handle the promise in any way.

By this point I recommend using async/await as you're entering something called "callback hell"

Make your event listener async:

```js
try {
    const channel = await client.channels.fetch(`1025902604728934442`);
    const msg = await channel.messages.fetch("1027438839435907142");

    await msg.react("");
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
}
```